# How to make POST request in robobrowser-python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests, robobrowser

http://robobrowser.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html

I'm trying to hit an API using `browser.open(myurl)` and looking for a RB method similar to `requests.post(url,data=data)`.

since robobrowser built on the top of requests and beautifulsoup so I think there must be a way to do so.

Comment: You'd normally use the form functionality to post; why do you need to post at all?

Comment: You mean the page uses AJAX requests from JavaScript? Use `response.session` in that case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can re-use the `requests.Session()` object of a `RoboBrowser` object to do your own `POST`s with the same cookies:

```
response = browser.session.post(...)
```

The `RoboBrowser` state won't be updated though; you'd have to pass the `response` object to the `RoboBrowser._update_state()` method.

```
browser._update_state(response)
```

For AJAX requests you wouldn't need to do this, however.

Take into account that future versions of the library may change how that works; it's not a documented method.

However, *normally* you'd post to a site because you are handling a form submit; leave that to the provided library functionality (`RoboBrowser.get_form()`, then `RoboBrowser.submit_form()`).

Comment: Yes, you would have to do so yes. Is that that big a problem? You'd have to do the same if you were to use *just* `requests`.

Answer (score 3):

As of version 0.5.3, you can send POST requests like this:

`browser.open(url, method='post', data=data)`

And of-coarse the browser's state and session will be updated automatically.

- [Related resolved issue on github.](https://github.com/jmcarp/robobrowser/issues/27)